# Find number of regex matches per line

Tags: regular-expression

Say I do a regex search for a class of characters, e.g.:

```
/[clsktb]
```

Is there a way to either sort lines by the number of matched characters, or to show the number of matches next to the line numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a variation:

```
:%s/^/\=len(split(getline('.'), '[clsktb]\zs')).' '/
```

That searches for line start, and for each line, gets its content and checks how many matches it has and puts the result back on the line.

Comment: Cool!: Vim is always a surprise to me! (+1)

Comment: The main strategy is the most important part of the answers. One minor thing: if I understand correctly, the result is correct if last char belongs to clsktb; otherwise is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 2):

**If** you must (using a  Vim *linked sausage* command):

```
:sign unplace *
:g/^/ let n = 0 | let c = -1 | while c != 0 | let c = search('[-]', '', line('.')) | let n = n + 1 | endwhile | if n > 1 | exe 'sign define ' . n . ' text=' . (n-1) | exe 'sign place ' . n . ' line=' . line('.') . ' name=' . n . ' file=' . expand('%:p') | endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Many Vims provide support for some scripting languages (Perl, Ruby, Python). If your vim has Perl support (some distributions don't provide it) you can use `:perl perl-command` and `:perldo perl-command`.

```
:perldo   $_ = y/clsktb// . " :: $_"
```

Perl's `y///` returns the number of occurrences of the chars in the default string (`$_`). The new $_ is concatenation of that number followed by " :: " and the line.

\thanks{EvergreenTree}

Comment: Do note that this requires a vim build that has perl support enabled.

Comment: @EvergreenTree, thank you, I always forget to say that.